I am compiling liboqc provider library using cmake and hitting below error?
Repo I tried:
git clone https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/oqs-provider.git


Command I executed:
cd oqs-provider

#OPTIONAL# git checkout d540c28

liboqs_DIR=$BUILD_DIR cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$WORKSPACE/oqs-provider \
  -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$BUILD_DIR \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -S . \
  -B _build
cmake --build _build

error I faced:
threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-threads_pthread.o): in function `CRYPTO_THREAD_get_local':
threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-thread_posix.o): in function `ossl_crypto_thread_native_spawn':
thread_posix.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-thread_posix.o): in function `ossl_crypto_thread_native_perform_join':
thread_posix.c:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-thread_posix.o): in function `ossl_crypto_mutex_try_lock':
thread_posix.c:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-dso_dlfcn.o): in function `dlfcn_globallookup':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-dso_dlfcn.o): in function `dlfcn_bind_func':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-dso_dlfcn.o): in function `dlfcn_load':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x345): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/bin/ld: dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x401): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-dso_dlfcn.o): in function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x4d6): undefined reference to `dladdr'
/usr/bin/ld: dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x547): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/quantumsafe/build/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-dso_dlfcn.o): in function `dlfcn_unload':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x6d8): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/oqs_test_groups.dir/build.make:116: test/oqs_test_groups] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:150: test/CMakeFiles/oqs_test_groups.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2

Could you someone guide me on compilation steps on OQC provider ?
Instruction I followed from the source:
https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/awb-quantum-safe-openssl/
compilation is failing
